# how tobind NIC to dpdk

Tags: drivers

How can I Bind NIC to DPDK ? I am working on Moongen project. I am not sure if I did correct.

```
sara@shayana:~/dpdk$ ./tools/dpdk_nic_bind.py --status

Network devices using DPDK-compatible driver
============================================
<none>

Network devices using kernel driver
===================================
0000:02:00.0 'NetXtreme II BCM5716 Gigabit Ethernet' if=eth0 drv=bnx2 unused=vfio-pci,uio_pci_generic *Active*
0000:02:00.1 'NetXtreme II BCM5716 Gigabit Ethernet' if=eth1 drv=bnx2 unused=vfio-pci,uio_pci_generic 

Other network devices
=====================
0000:01:00.0 '82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection' unused=vfio-pci,uio_pci_generic
0000:01:00.1 '82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection' unused=vfio-pci,uio_pci_generic
sara@shayana:~/dpdk$  .
```

Comment: What is DPDK?  What does it do?  What're you trying to achieve?

Comment: DPDK is a set of libraries and drivers for fast packet processing.http://dpdk.org/ @ThomasW.

Comment: you can bind a NIC using this command ./tools/dpdk_nic_bind.py -b uio_pci_generic 0000:01:00.0

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu helps you to do that in a persistent way with `/etc/dpdk/interfaces`

I'm not sure if your cards are supported, but for you it could look like:

```
pci 0000:01:00.0 uio_pci_generic
pci 0000:01:00.1 uio_pci_generic
```

More can be found at https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/serverguide/DPDK.html#dpdk-config-dev

Comment: :Thank you so much  , I have found the solution already.